# Using Order By in inner query with Custom metadata fails to retrieve all results

Tags: soql, custom-metadata

Salesforce claims that this if fixed.

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001qUzCQAU&title=using-order-by-in-subquery-in-custom-metadata-types-does-not-return-all-the-records

But it seems like it has cropped up again.

I know the workaround can be fetch the data and use comparable interface. But just checking if anyone else is also facing this.

```
SELECT Label, (SELECT Id, Assmt2_0ProgramTable__c,Priority__c FROM Assmt2_0ProgramPriorities__r 
                 WHERE IsActive__c = TRUE 
                 ORDER BY Priority__c ASC ) 
 FROM Assmt2_0ClassTable__mdt WHERE IsActive__c = TRUE
```

[image]

And if I remove order by.

```
SELECT Label, (SELECT Id, Assmt2_0ProgramTable__c,Priority__c FROM Assmt2_0ProgramPriorities__r WHERE
        IsActive__c = TRUE ) FROM Assmt2_0ClassTable__mdt WHERE IsActive__c = TRUE
```

[image]